# Unable to connect Huawei u8110 via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am not able to connect my PC to Android device using adb. I have enabled USB debugging option on the device.

The `adb devices` options shows following output

[image]

Device Manager output is shown below

[image]

What could be going wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your device doesn't provide a serial number.  There's a patch out there to fix this, but it hasn't (yet) been integrated into the downloadable tools.

**However**: you can also use the *-d* option to adb, which means connect to the "only usb device" ignoring the serial number.

See also: http://www.newtondev.com/2011/01/21/getting-adb-to-list-your-android-vodafone-845-huawei-u8120-and-get-debugging-working/

Answer (score 0):

Your command line result shows "? device" which means your device is connected.